# Concating None with string. with not none string output

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I am working with a dataframe say df_json. There is a column in the dataframe call 'metadata' with is json like object so I want to make a new column extracting information from it and giving the column new name 'headline'.

```
df_json['headline'] = df_json['location']+ ' '+ df_json["metadata"].str['standout'].str['bullet1'] + ' '+ df_json["metadata"].str['standout'].str['bullet2'] + ' '+ df_json["metadata"].str['standout'].str['bullet3']
```

So far all good but I have noticed that some rows don't have any data in 'bullet1 or bullet 2 etc hence the return value in 'None' hence some rows give None when it should at least contain the location which is never None, so I feel when it returns None in case of
say

```
df_json["metadata"].str['standout'].str['bullet1'][1]
```

I want to replace it with an empty string '   '. Please let me know if I can do it for all rows automatically using pandas?

Comment: Have you tried using `.fillna()` ? It is good for replacing None values with another value.

Comment: oh yes it does work, thanks